# Setting up Docker Postgres inside Python container

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I currently have a python3 web application running in a docker image. I am trying to restore a local database dump in the docker container (dump.pgsql) and connect to that database within my application.
I am having a couple issues.

From within the Python container I can't seem to download any version of postgres (9.1-9.6) and once I am able to restore the database, how would I get connect (I am currently connecting via Login URI to the cloud database).

My DockerFile is:

```
FROM python:3
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
EXPOSE 5000
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
#Run Postgres Locally 
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-9.2
RUN postgres restore code.pgsql
CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

And I run the command with

```
docker build -t code .
docker run --name code -ti -p 8000:8000 code
```

Comment: Running both an application and database in a single container isn't generally considered a good idea. Most examples you will find won't be running containers this way. I'd recommended reading through https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/ for an example on using Docker Compose to run your application and the database as two separate containers (separating your code and dependencies from the database). The example is for Django, but it should translate to any Python application fairly well. I'd recommend closing this question if you decide to go this route.